# Context3D.supportsVideoTexture is undefined

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stage3d

I'm trying to get VideoTexture working in an Adobe Air app and I'm having real trouble with the basics and getting it working on my machine.

I'm also using Stage3Dproxy and I wonder if this causes the problem, but Context3D.supportsVideoTexture is always undefined.

I've got a fairly hefty NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M which I think is fairly new and should be upto the job!?

The Adobe Stage3D support swf never loads for me, so I'm wondering if this relates to the problem
https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/stage3d-unsupported-chipsets-drivers-flash.html

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: this is AIR 17 minimum feature, set your swf_version to match.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention the swf_version is currently set to 30, for Air 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BotMaster was right - I'd not set the right swf-version in this particular project file.